# 16.04: Vim colors don't match normal terminal colors

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal, vim, colors

Ever since I upgraded to 16.04, the colors in Vim haven't matched the colors in my normal terminal regardless of what color scheme I give it. Here's my normal terminal colors:

[image: normal terminal colors] and the

And "normal" Vim colors

[image: "normal" Vim colors].

I know it isn't my .vimrc because it looks the same whether I have my current config in my home folder or not. Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Could you be please more precise: Which colors do you expect to match? Both `ls` and `vim` can choose from 16 million colors independently from each other. Okay, realistically they'll choose from the nowadays standard 256-color palette, which is still a lot. Anyway... if you upgraded from 14.04 then the relevant change is probably the default value of `$TERM` which is now `xterm-256color` rather than `xterm`. Try reverting this for the time being by executing `export TERM=xterm` to see if this gives a proper workaround for you.

Comment: Should I put `export TERM=xterm` into my .bashrc, or should I only run it when I'm about to run vim?

Comment: I guess there's a command that you can place in your `.vimrc` so that you don't need to set TERM. I'm not sure what it is. Or you can place this in your .bashrc: `alias vim='TERM=xterm vim'` and then it's automatically applied for vim only.